# Flask Login user session with LDAP

Tags: python, flask, ldap, flask-login

I have a Flask webapp that allows user's to login using Active Directory credentials.  What I would like to have is the AD **'displayName'** which is just an attribute of the username, to be used throughout the session.

What I have tried:

- User can login and authenticate successfully
- When login occurs it makes a call to LDAP to get the 'displayName' attribute
- I make the 'displayName' a global variable so that I can use it in a form later in the session
- The problem is if another user tries to access that page the previous logged in user shows up as the displayName because this was a global variable

**What is the best way to be able to call on LDAP attributes but on a per user session basis?**

```
    def get_ldap_connection():
        conn = ldap.initialize(app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'])
        return conn

    class User(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(100))

        def __init__(self, username, password, display_name):
            self.username = username
            self.display_name = display_name

        @staticmethod
        def try_login(username, password):
            conn = get_ldap_connection()
            conn.simple_bind_s(domain+username, password)

        @staticmethod
        def whoami(username, password):
            conn = get_ldap_connection()
            conn.simple_bind_s(domain + username, password)
            base = "OU=Users,OU=Corp,DC=mydomain,DC=ad"
            criteria = ldap.filter.filter_format('(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))', [username])
        userattribute = ['displayName']

            result = conn.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, userattribute)

            global displayName
            displayName = result[0][1]['displayName'][0]

        def is_authenticated(self):
            return True

        def is_active(self):
            return True

        def is_anonymous(self):
            return False

        def get_id(self):
            return unicode(self.id)
```

Comment: Maybe you can clean up `displayName` after use logged out. And flask has `flask.g` object could help you to store values globally

Comment: Hmm I may have got this working using session in Flask.  I need to test to verify. Your comment put me on that track.